# WINDBG: Viewing values of variables in unnamed namespace

Tags: windows, debugging, visual-c++, windbg

Is there some kind of trick to see the values of a variable in an *unnamed* namespace once you break into Windbg? I locate the variable like so:

```
0:000> x mod!ns::*myvar*
70f7afc6          mod!ns::`anonymous namespace'::`dynamic initializer for 'myvar'' (void)
717bb799          mod!ns::`anonymous namespace'::`dynamic atexit destructor for 'myvar'' (void)
71a00718          mod!ns::`anonymous namespace'::myvar = <no type information>
```

`myvar` is basically a `std::map` and there is a debugger visualizer (natvis) available for it such that `?? myvar` should show something usable. However because of that anonymous namespace getting in between, I can't seem to figure out the right syntax to display the values in `myvar`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Officially anonymous namespaces are not supported in watch window under visual studio debugger as recently as 7/17](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/expressions-in-the-debugger)

historically windbg has been a mile or two behind in implementing these fancy displays

that said is your name space nested ?.

I assume yes because you have a ns after the module **mod!ns::**

if that is not the case **x mymap** would yield a clickable dml link 
it would properly display the type   if it was nested windbg would spit **no type information available**

in that case you can cast them to the actual type with the pointer   like **mod!std::map..........xxx...**

here is a contrived source code compiled and executed under windbg that demos some possibilities

source of first file this contains **an unnamed ns and a named nested unnamed ns and also references another file that contains an anonymous namespace**

```
#include "anonall.h"
namespace {
    map<char, const char*> mymap;
    const char *Greek_Alphabets[ALLOCSIZ] = { "Alp","Bet","Gam","Del","Eps" };
}
namespace ns {
    namespace {
        map<char, const char*> mymap;
        const char *Greek_Alphabets[ALLOCSIZ]={ 
        "Alpha","Beta","Gamma","Delta","Epsilon" };
    }
}
void anonnsptwo(void);
void anonnsptre(void) {
    cout << "\nfrom Anonymous NS Map in " << __FILE__ << " " << __LINE__ << "\n\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < ALLOCSIZ; i++) {
        mymap.insert(pair<char, const char*>(char('M' + i), Greek_Alphabets[i]));
    }
    map<char, const char*>::iterator iter = mymap.begin();
    for (iter; iter != mymap.end(); iter++)
        cout << iter->first << " = " << iter->second << "\n";
}
int main(void) {
    anonnsptre();
    cout << "\nfrom Anonymous NS Map in " << __FILE__ << " " << __LINE__ << "\n\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < ALLOCSIZ; i++) {
        ns::mymap.insert(pair<char, const char*>(char('A'+i),ns::Greek_Alphabets[i]));
    }
    map<char, const char*>::iterator iter = ns::mymap.begin();
    for (iter; iter != ns::mymap.end(); iter++)
        cout << iter->first << " = " << iter->second << "\n";
    anonnsptwo();
    return 0;
}
```

source of second file referenced by first file

```
#include "anonall.h"
namespace ns {
    namespace {
        map<char, const char*> mymap;
        const char *Greek_Alphabets[ALLOCSIZ]={"Zeta","Eta","Theta","Iota","Kappa"};
    }
}
void anonnsptwo(void) {
    cout << "\nfrom Anonymous Namespace Map in " << __FILE__ << "\n\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < ALLOCSIZ; i++) {
    ns::mymap.insert(pair<char, const char*>(char('Z'-i),ns::Greek_Alphabets[i]));
    }
    map<char, const char*>::iterator iter = ns::mymap.begin();
    for (iter; iter != ns::mymap.end(); iter++)
        cout << iter->first << " = " << iter->second << "\n";
}
```

the common header file contents

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#define ALLOCSIZ 5
using namespace std;
```

compiled and linked with vs community 2017 (15.6.4) cmd prompt

```
:\>echo off

ls
anonall.h  anonone.cpp  anontwo.cpp

cl /Zi /W4 /analyze /EHsc /Od /nologo anonone.cpp anontwo.cpp /link /release /nologo

anonone.cpp
anontwo.cpp
Compiling...
Generating Code...

ls
anonall.h                       anonone.obj                     anontwo.obj
anonone.cpp                     anonone.pdb                     vc140.pdb
anonone.exe                     anontwo.cpp
anonone.nativecodeanalysis.xml  anontwo.nativecodeanalysis.xml
```

executing the binary

```
anonone.exe
from Anonymous NS Map in anonone.cpp 15

M = Alp
N = Bet
O = Gam
P = Del
Q = Eps

from Anonymous NS Map in anonone.cpp 25

A = Alpha
B = Beta
C = Gamma
D = Delta
E = Epsilon

from Anonymous Namespace Map in anontwo.cpp

V = Kappa
W = Iota
X = Theta
Y = Eta
Z = Zeta
```

using cdb just to show the result without user intervention

if one uses windbg instead of cdb the results of x*!*mymap will be clickable links

notice the size = 5  and notice the other two anonymous mymaps with no type information
(your question of how to print these mymaps follows this )

setting the breakpoint on first files return (end of program)

**grep -in ret.* anonone.cpp

33:     return 0;**  << line number is 33

enabling line no info setting a conditional deferred break on src line and on hitting that break printing the results of x command and quitting

**>cdb -c ".lines;bu `anonone.cpp:33` \"x *!*mymap*\";g;q" anonone.exe**
e

```
cdb -c ".lines;bu `anonone.cpp:33` \"x *!*mymap*\";g;q" anonone.exe

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.16299.15 X86

0:000> cdb: Reading initial command '.lines;bu `anonone.cpp:33` "x *!*mymap*";g;q'

snipp======================

0118b938          anonone!mymap = { size=0x5 }
01175198          anonone!mymap$initializer$ = 0x01101040
011742c0          anonone!`anonymous namespace'::`dynamic atexit destructor for 'mymap'' (void)
01101040          anonone!`anonymous namespace'::`dynamic initializer for 'mymap'' (void)
011742e0          anonone!ns::`anonymous namespace'::`dynamic atexit destructor for 'mymap'' (void)
011742d0          anonone!ns::`anonymous namespace'::`dynamic atexit destructor for 'mymap'' (void)
01101080          anonone!ns::`anonymous namespace'::`dynamic initializer for 'mymap'' (void)
01101060          anonone!ns::`anonymous namespace'::`dynamic initializer for 'mymap'' (void)
0118b930          anonone!ns::`anonymous namespace'::mymap = <no type information>
0118b960          anonone!ns::`anonymous namespace'::mymap = <no type information>

quit:
```

you can now cast both the address of mymap @  0x0118b960 and  0x0118b930  as std::map
(do x anonone!std::map hit tab tab tab to find  the type info  make it a pointer and stick the address  and use the dx expression evaluator to get the display)

that is like **dx ( anonone!std:map......xx..yy..zz *) 0x0118b960**

```
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x2c:
771d05a6 cc              int     3
Processing initial command '$$>a< displayanon.txt'
0:000> $$>a< displayanon.txt
ModLoad: 6b450000 6b453000   C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.DLL
00d6b938          anonone!mymap = { size=0x5 }
00d55198          anonone!mymap$initializer$ = 0x00ce1040
00d542c0          anonone!`anonymous namespace'::`dynamic atexit destructor for 'mymap'' (void)
00ce1040          anonone!`anonymous namespace'::`dynamic initializer for 'mymap'' (void)
00d542e0          anonone!ns::`anonymous namespace'::`dynamic atexit destructor for 'mymap'' (void)
00d542d0          anonone!ns::`anonymous namespace'::`dynamic atexit destructor for 'mymap'' (void)
00ce1080          anonone!ns::`anonymous namespace'::`dynamic initializer for 'mymap'' (void)
00ce1060          anonone!ns::`anonymous namespace'::`dynamic initializer for 'mymap'' (void)
00d6b930          anonone!ns::`anonymous namespace'::mymap = <no type information>
00d6b960          anonone!ns::`anonymous namespace'::mymap = <no type information>


this is the type which you can get by using x {mod}!{std::map {wildcard}}

class std::map<char,char const *,std::less<char>,std::allocator<std::pair<char const ,char const *> > >
   +0x000 _Mypair          : 
mymap                 : { size=0x5 } 
snipped
    [0x0]            : 77 'M', "Alp" [Type: 
    [0x1]            : 78 'N', "Bet" [Type: 
    [0x2]            : 79 'O', "Gam" [Type: 
    [0x3]            : 80 'P', "Del" [Type: 
    [0x4]            : 81 'Q', "Eps" [Type: 

0:000> dx ( std::map<char,char const *,std::less<char>,std::allocator<std::pair<char const ,char const *> > > *) 0x00d6b930
( std::map<char,char const *,std::less<char>,std::allocator<std::pair<char const ,char const *> > > *) 0x00d6b930 
snipped
    [0x1]            : 65 'A', "Alpha" [Type:
    [0x2]            : 66 'B', "Beta" [Type:
    [0x3]            : 67 'C', "Gamma" [Type:
    [0x4]            : 68 'D', "Delta" [Type:
    [0x5]            : 69 'E', "Epsilon" [Type:

0:000> dx ( std::map<char,char const *,std::less<char>,std::allocator<std::pair<char const ,char const *> > > *) 0x00d6b960
( std::map<char,char const *,std::less<char>,std::allocator<std::pair<char const ,char const *> > > *) 0x00d6b960 
snipped
    [0x1]            : 86 'V', "Kappa" [Type: std::pair<char const ,char const *>]
    [0x2]            : 87 'W', "Iota" [Type: std::pair<char const ,char const *>]
    [0x3]            : 88 'X', "Theta" [Type: std::pair<char const ,char const *>]
    [0x4]            : 89 'Y', "Eta" [Type: std::pair<char const ,char const *>]
    [0x5]            : 90 'Z', "Zeta" [Type: std::pair<char const ,char const *>]
```

Comment: You, sir, are a wizard. I don't even know if this helps (yet) but I am going to mark this as answer just for your effort. Appreciate it!

Comment: That ability to hit tab multiple times and cycle through the different instantiations of std::map was mind-blowing! It's now so easy to run 'dx' on any address. The trouble was always with how to find the long-winded STL type to cast the address to. Thanks so much @blabb. Much appreciated.